# Windows 8 apps - what is the best place to handle charms events?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Does it matter where charms events such as `SettingsPane.CommandsRequested` or `DataTransferManager.DataRequested` are handled and if so what is the recommended place to do that - a `Page`constructor, `OnNavigatedTo` method, `Page.Loaded` event handler etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a global registration, your best bet in a XAML app is in the [OnWindowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onwindowcreated.aspx) override.

This ensures that the code is run after your window is created and on the correct thread (both required for any GetForCurrentView APIs to work) and only once for each window, regardless of how many times your app may be activated for different contracts.

Alternatively, you can take the per-page approach, if some of your pages will register for these events and others will not, or if you want to maintain differing, decoupled implementations. In this case, I would suggest using the [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx) method to register them, and ensure that you unregister them in [OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx). This is important because some of these events (like DataRequested) can only have one handler registered at a time. So the current page should unregister its handler *before* it's unloaded (thus OnNavigat**ing**From is a better choice than OnNavigatedFrom).

Hope that helps.